# Step by step, how do I use RemoteFX in Windows 7 machine (not a virtualized guest OS)?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, remote-desktop, remotefx, remmina

I understand RemoteFX will allow me to use graphically intensive programs remotely on my Windows 7 machine. I have Windows 7 Ultimate.

I also have Remmina (which supports RemoteFX) installed on an Ubuntu 14.10 laptop. When I connect via RemoteFX I get a black screen.

I'd love to use Adobe Lightroom (graphics intensive app) remotely.

There are lots of tutorials online about how to do it with Windows Server and virtual machines, but I want to do it with just a normal Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it doesn't exist in Windows 7